# Objective C - Do Not Refresh/Reload Parent ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, xcode7

I have a Instagram like timeline that allows users to post images and videos using a UITableView.

The user can tap on an image and it opens up larger like a lightbox where the background dims. The user then can tap anywhere to close it.

The user can tap on a mpmovieplayer video to open the video full screen. The user can than tap the done button to close it.

All this works fine, my issue is my timeline uses pagination and pages after every 10th object that is loaded. Objects 1 - 10 are fine as when the user closes the image or video it brings them back to the same spot on the timeline. If the user has paged and is on say the 24th object and taps it. Once they close it, it brings them back to the 10th object on the timeline.

How can I prevent the parent ViewController from reloading or refreshing so that it brings the user back to the last spot they left off?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.tableView.tag = 1;
    if (self.shouldReload) {
        [self loadObjects];
    } else {
        self.shouldReload = YES;
    }
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:196.0f/360.0f saturation:100.0f/100.0f brightness:94.0f/100.0f alpha:1];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    delegate.container.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeDefault;

}
```

Below is how I am calling the lightbox type image:

```
    // Create image info
    JTSImageInfo *imageInfo = [[JTSImageInfo alloc] init];
#if TRY_AN_ANIMATED_GIF == 1
    imageInfo.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media.giphy.com/media/O3QpFiN97YjJu/giphy.gif"];
#else
    //imageInfo.image = photoImageView.image;
    imageInfo.image = myPhoto;
#endif
    imageInfo.referenceRect = photoImageView.frame;
    imageInfo.referenceView = photoImageView.superview;
    imageInfo.referenceContentMode = photoImageView.contentMode;
    imageInfo.referenceCornerRadius = photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius;

    // Setup view controller
    JTSImageViewController *imageViewer = [[JTSImageViewController alloc]
                                           initWithImageInfo:imageInfo
                                           mode:JTSImageViewControllerMode_Image
                                           backgroundStyle:JTSImageViewControllerBackgroundOption_Blurred];

    // Present the view controller.
    [imageViewer showFromViewController:self transition:JTSImageViewControllerTransition_FromOriginalPosition];
            });
        }];
}
```

Comment: You can post your code here to help you.

Comment: @Stretcher25 : TableView controller maintains its scroll position unless it is reloaded. So you must be having self.tableView.reloadData() either inside your viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods. If yes handle it appropriately and everything will be fine :)

Comment: reloadData() is not present.

Comment: Can you please post ViewWillAppear code and also code u are using to bring lightbox